# How to create a platform for students asking questions quickly and privately?

Tags: technology-in-education

When studying math in class, many students have a few moments falling behind, and they are reluctant to ask a quick question.

Do we have a way (like an online web page or tool) for students to quicky access (with privacy and without any registration) for asking math questions?

The following is what I really want to have:

- Students are given a code from the lecturer to access the platform. It might take less than 5 seconds for students to start asking questions using the given code.
- No information of students will be provided due to no registration. Only the lecturer can see the questions. And the lecturer can determine to answer them directly in class or reply back to the student who asked the question privately using the platfrom.
- Easy to type math formulas or upload images.

Thank for any suggestion.

---

Remark:

- The code is used to distinguish different subjects or classes.

Comment: If it doesn't exist yet, this is a great idea. (If you're going to reply back, they'll need an account.)

Comment: @Sue They don't need an account if they are still on the platform. The idea is that we want a temporary interaction during class time. After the class, then we can use more heavily things, like emails.

Comment: I've been teaching online for the past 2 years. My students ask questions in zoom, just to me, and that works great. Good luck figuring something out.

Comment: @Sue I've been using Zoom and Google meet. But only few students were willing to come out since anyone knows who is asking.

Comment: Zoom supports private text messages.

Comment: I thought you were teaching in person. If you're on zoom, you just need to be sure you have things set up right. Students send private chat messages to me in zoom all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google form satisfies 1 & 2, and if you have a browser open to the google-sheet that holds the responses. I am not 100% certain that the google-sheet refreshes itself, so you may have to periodically refresh to see if questions are being asked.

I do not know of anyway to satisfy (3) as well